# having trouble centering table in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, xhtml, safari, google-chrome

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I cannot seem to center table with two images between 2   in side the right . Works in firefox, opera, ie8. XHTML and CSS validates.

Comment: You're going to have to show some code for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes on centering.

1. Always provide a width to the object you are trying to center
2. Once a width is set then use `margin:0 auto;` on that element
3. Enjoy seeing your code centered...
4. Also, if your element is inline (anchor, span, etc) make sure you display the element as `display:block;`

If you show some code I'm sure it's a simple fix.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to supply the width to center the object. http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered.html

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width and margin explicitly to add to 100%:
`width:90%;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;`